# PvApi for prosilica camera

Tags: c++, c, image, g++, xcode5

I am using [prosilica camera](http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/us/news/news-display/article/gige-vision-sdk-update.html) on Mac os x 10.8.5. I downloaded the SDK for Mac OS X.
I try to execute the examples on the SDK but always I got this errors.

```
> make sample
g++-4.2   -O3  -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -I/usr/include -D_x64 -D_OSX -Wall -I../../inc-pc -D_REENTRANT  ListCameras.cpp -o ListCameras -lpthread -lz -Bdynamic -lm -lc -L../../bin-pc/x64 -lPvAPI
make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [sample] Error 1
```

But when i run g++ -v on terminal I got:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

What is the error ? could help me please ?

Comment: what all files do you have in your folder ? Also can you try changing this in your makefile "-L../../bin-pc/x64 -lPvAPI" part before " -lpthread " Or before "ListCameras.cpp" ?

Comment: @user3217310 thanks for your helps, you can download the sdk files for mac os x on http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/us/products/legacy.html

Comment: @user3217310, there is an ARCH file that contains a lot of information and constraints, so I can not change only the MakeFile.

Answer (score 0):

TO understand the error open your ARCH file and see the error

```
g++-4.2   -O3  -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -I/usr/include -D_x64 -D_OSX -Wall -I../../inc-pc -D_REENTRANT  ListCameras.cpp -o ListCameras -lpthread -lz -Bdynamic -lm -lc -L../../bin-pc/x64 -lPvAPI
make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
```

It is running fine up-to the 24 line of ARCH file printing g++-$(VER) but after that It is not able to link.

So I guess try to change the ARCH file according to your directories especially this part

```
## few locations
INC_DIR   = ../../inc-pc
BIN_DIR   = ../../bin-pc/$(CPU)
LIB_DIR   = ../../lib-pc/$(CPU)
OBJ_DIR   = ./obj/$(CPU)
EXTRA_LIB = -lpthread -lz
```

Complete the paths of all the directories.

Or mainly it needs the path to libPvAPI.a library so you can also change the following part directly :

```
## libs (shared/static)
PVLIB   = -L$(BIN_DIR) -lPvAPI
```

to

```
PVLIB   = -L/fullpath -lPvAPI
```

by fullpath I mean something like -L/home/username/folder1/.../ .

Comment: if you found the answer useful ... it could be more helpful to others if up voted or accepted